# Bug in pushing an object to a shared_ptr<string_view> queue

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, smart-pointers, string-view

In this code I created 2 functions in addition to the main function. One pushes an object to the queue,
and the other one gets the user input and adds it to the queue as a `shared pointer<string_view>.`

**When trying to print the user input which we added to the queue, it does not print anything**.
The thing is when you push `shared_ptr<string_view>("Hello World!")` instead of the user input, it do prints `"Hello World!"`

I do understand (or thinks I do) it is related to the fact that "Hello World!" is temporary while the buffer variable is local - but I dont know how to fix that....

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void addToQueue(queue<shared_ptr<string_view>> &queue, shared_ptr<string_view> object ) {
    queue.push(object);
}

void readInput(queue<shared_ptr<string_view>> &queue) {
    string buffer;
    //get user input
    cin >> buffer;

    // When changing this row to
    // addToQueue(make_shared<string_view>("Hello World!"));
    //"Hello World!" will be printed
    addToQueue(queue, make_shared<string_view>(buffer)); 
}

int main() {
    queue<shared_ptr<string_view>> queue;
    readInput(queue);
    cout << *queue.front().get() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is `string_view` valid after destruction of `buffer`? Just use `vector<string>`. And there is no need of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: The problem is it isn't my whole code - so if want to change it to  `vector<string>` i would have to change most of my headers and classes........

Comment: That is the right way I think. `container<shared_ptr<string_view>>` is nonsense, at least in your code.

Comment: If you really cannot change, put strings into another place (like `vector<string>`) and enqueue the reference to this place. Remove the element at dequeue

Comment: Yep - in this code you are right. My problem is that it is neccesery in my real code, so it would take me ALOT of time to change it to 'vector<shared_ptr<std::string>>'. Dont you think there is another way doing it with 'view_string'? I mean, with the temprary 'const char*' it works  so I guess there is a way doing it.

Comment: You also can make custom deleter for `shared_ptr<string_view>` removing the original string element in the `vector<string>` object. Btw,  why did you use `shared_ptr<string_view>` in your real code?

Comment: Well, for some reason when I gave a struct which contains `std::string` as parameter to a fuction it was not copied correctly, but when I used `string_view` it did. So I just continued to use `std::string_view` until I got stuck with this bug.